# website opens a download window when I navigate

Tags: apache

I have been researching this and can't find anything in Google, but basically whenever I try to navigate to another page in my website, the browser opens a download window instead asking me to download a pagetitle.gz file

Comment: It's uncommon to have pages with a .gz extension. Leave them as their default html / json extensions. The browser is clever enough to detect they're compressed and decompress them

Comment: Well,  perhaps the browsers are not that clever as they didn't decompress for me. I had to do the fix below to make the site work.  Other than that I get an option to download the page in .gz form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I'm not sure how it broke and what caused it, but I know this fixed it. Simply add this to the bottom of your htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
   AddCharset utf-8 .html
   AddCharset utf-8 .json
   AddEncoding gzip .gz
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "(\.html|\.html\.gz)$">
   ForceType text/html
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(\.json|\.json\.gz)$">
   ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
```